# How to determine Windows version from a batch script for an inactive drive?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command-prompt

How can one get the version of Windows from the shell (command prompt) via a batch script for a drive that does not contain the active OS?  I was hoping for some file that I could test, but it turns out things are a little more vague than I'd hoped.  This should be able to determine the version of Windows for all NT releases from 2000 to 8.1.

Comment: What do you mean by Windows version for an inactive drive?

Comment: So you have drives that have been removed from a computer and are therefore not actually booted into the OS.  The drive is therefore "inactive" in terms of the OS running on it presently.

Comment: This is not really possible if you have non-standard Windows installations (folders with non-standard names, paths set to non-default values etc). Additionaly, there can be more than one Windows installation on one hard disk.

Comment: @ylluminate - Fine, I can understand wanting to know the version of the running OS, and I can see wanting to catalog inactive drives, but I don't see how they are related. Unless the inactive drive has an alternate OS and you want to catalog multiple OS versions that might be available at bootup? Or perhaps OS versions available as virtual machines?

Comment: Totally diff application.  Don't really need to get into the why's of it; simply trying to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can load the windows registry from the "inactive OS' Drive" and read the version from it:

this is not tested, but it's something like this:

```
set SYSTEM_DRIVE=D:
reg load "HKU\ttt" "%SYSTEM_DRIVE%\Windows\System32\config\SOFTWARE"
reg query "HKU\ttt\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName
reg unload "HKU\ttt"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would think a fairly robust method would be to look at the file version metadata for a standard OS file such as %SystemRoot%\system32\winver.exe.

Comment: I really like this method.  I'll check it out and report back when I have some time over the next week.

Comment: Don't forget about the command line one: **ver** It's ver useful for batch script operations.

Comment: Nice try, but the `ver` command reports the _active_ OS version (not what this question was asking).

Answer (score -1):

I did the following (from command prompt):
'findstr /i "f.i.l.e.v.e.r.s.i.o.n" kernel32.dll > ver'
The dots are required because the metadata is unicode, and findstr will thus ignore the
zeros that are between the letters (dot being a wildcard for "any single character").
(see: findstr /?). The snippet can be examined in notepad or, on some systems that still support "EDIT", "EDIT /70 VER". The output is still unicode, but it can be "prettied up"
using programming (f/e vbscript). the raw material can be examined "as is":
F i l e V e r s i o n     6 . 1 . 7 6 0 1 . 1 9 1 3 5   ( w i n 7 s p 1 _ g d r . 1 6 0 1 2 1 - 1 7 1 8 )     2. Googling windows versions yielded: me=4.9, 2000=5.0, xp=5.1, vista=6.0, 7=6.1, 8=6.2, 8.1=6.3, 10=10.0, (then a bunch more while microsoft put out fires, then 11=21H2. (7601 is the "build" number") Above taken from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).